# Can't find sDNA plugin with QGIS

Tags: qgis, sdna

I assume I am making a very rookie mistake here, but I can't find an sDNA plugin in QGIS. I installed and authorised the software according to the instructions. I also checked "show also experimental plugins" box. Does sDNA needs to be installed in a specific folder in order for QGIS being able to find it?

On the other hand, ArcGIS is able to find the sDNA, but shows an error saying "click to repair project item" which doesn't seem to fix the problem.

I am running Windows 10, GIS version 3.4 Madeira, ArcGIS Pro and sDNA v4_0_3.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked which versions of QGIS and Arc the plugin-version is compatible with?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Erik. And you are right, sDNA is not compatible with QGIS version I am using.

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and ArcGIS Pro you wish to ask about within this particular question so that it and its answers can be focused on what you have tried and where you are stuck with that software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently sDNA supports only ArcGIS 10.x and QGIS 2.x - sorry but until this changes (there are plans afoot to update it) you will need to use older versions of the host software. If you didn't want to do that you can call sDNA directly on shapefiles from the command line.